# Spring Data query: how to express 'at least one of the element of this list is member of...'

Tags: spring-data-jpa

For now, I have a Repository class, that has a Department and a list of Users.
For a connected user, I want to retrieve all repositories from a dedicated department or repositories where the user is listed.

Here is how it is managed using Spring Data query:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct repository " +
        "from Repository repository " +
        "left join repository.users " +
        "where analysis.department =:department " +
        "or :connectedUser member of repository.users ",
        countQuery = "select count(distinct repository) from Repository repository")
    Page<Analysis> findAllByUser(Pageable pageable,
                                 @Param("department") Department department,
                                 @Param("connectedUser") User connectedUser);
```

It is working well.

I have now to integrate a new feature.
The repository can be linked to a list of UserGroup.

I would like to update my method with something like this:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct repository " +
        "from Repository repository " +
        "left join repository.users " +
        "left join repository.userGroups " +
        "where analysis.department =:department " +
        "or :connectedUser member of repository.users " +
        "or (at least one element of :userGroupList) member of repository.userGroups ",
        countQuery = "select count(distinct repository) from Repository repository")
    Page<Analysis> findAllByUser(Pageable pageable,
                                 @Param("department") Department department,
                                 @Param("connectedUser") User connectedUser,
                                 @Param("userGroupList") Set<UserGroup> userGroupList;
```

Is there a way to do that? If so, what should I use instead of **(at least one element of userGroupList)**?

Maybe, *member of* is not the best approach... If so, could you advise another one? My main objective is to be able to manage that in a single query to get page results.

Thanks in advance for all help and advice you could provide! :)

If it can help, here are entities used (high level, not in detail):

```
public class Repository {
    private String name;
    private Department department;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<>();
```

```
public class UserGroup {
    private String name;
    private Department department;
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: `or repository.userGroups in :userGoupList` (!?)

Comment: Hello xerx593, thanks for your comment. Maybe I'm wrong, but if I add what you just propose, all user groups linked to a repository should be in userGroupList, no ? I need at least one element from userGroupList to be in repository.userGroups, not all.

Comment: Hi! :-) No,  the semantics is "any" (not "all") ...and i mean to replace the (complete) line: `or (at least one element of :userGoupList) member of repository.userGroups` ;)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will test your proposal.

Comment: Hello, just tried your proposal: add 'or repository.userGroups in :userGroupList' in the Query. I get the following exception: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [UserGroup] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]**. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: in orignal posting not: `@Param("userGroupList") Set<UserGroup> userGoupList` (is a set not a UserGroup, correct!?)

Comment: Hello, I confirm parameter is a Set<UserGroup>, not a UserGroup. That's why I don't understand the raised exception :)

Comment: maybe the input (of repository ..has wrong type)? (illegal argument is a *runtime exception* not compile;)

Comment: More info after new tests... What I see when debugging what is in userGroupList: [UserGroup@63da6cbb, UserGroup@285d588]. Exception thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [UserGroup@63da6cbb] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]. It seems it is using only the first element of the HashSet...